# show json body in a google chart

Tags: javascript, json, object, charts, google-visualization

I have a huge problem with charts. Im trying to show just a few json value in the google chart, but I always get errors. 
From the JSON body I only need the 'purchases all' and the 'Date' from the last month for the Chart. All the examples I have seen, they already got a static self defined Jsonbody. I hope you can help me and tell me what im doing wrong :(.

This is my jsFile, with the API response:

```
    request(requestApi, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
    return res.reject(error);
    }

    var dataJson = JSON.parse(body);

    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataJson);
        data.addRows([
        [{v: dataJson[0].total_purchases.purchases_all, 
          f: dataJson[0].total_purchases.date }]
        ]);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'chart '
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'week'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'counts',
                viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                viewWindow: {
                    max: 300,
                    min: 0
                }
            },
            bars: 'vertical',
            width: 600,
            height: 500
        };


    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('the_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    }
```

The response from the API is this:

```
    {
      "total_purchases": [
      {
        "number": 0,
        "purchases_website": 11,
        "purchases_app": 10,
        "purchases_all": 21,
        "date": "2016-07-01"
      },
      {
        "number": 3,
        "purchases_website": 19,
        "purchases_app": 32,
        "purchases_all": 51,
        "date": "2016-05-01"
      },
     {
        "number": 1,
        "purchases_website": 31,
        "purchases_app": 34,
        "purchases_all": 65,
        "date": "2016-06-01"
      },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "purchases_website": 20,
        "purchases_app": 12,
        "purchases": 32,
        "date": "2016-08-01"
     }
    ]
   }
```

When I console log the JSON.parse(body) I get this:

[imageHERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IueaU.png)

Comment: to create the google data table, the json needs to be [in a specific format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Comment: @WhiteHat but I dont exactly know how to do it. can you give me one more hint? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the json is not in the format google expects,
load the data table manually

1. create blank data table
2. add columns
3. add rows with data from json

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataJson = {"total_purchases": [
      {
        "number": 0,
        "purchases_website": 11,
        "purchases_app": 10,
        "purchases_all": 21,
        "date": "2016-07-01"
      },
      {
        "number": 3,
        "purchases_website": 19,
        "purchases_app": 32,
        "purchases_all": 51,
        "date": "2016-05-01"
      },
      {
        "number": 1,
        "purchases_website": 31,
        "purchases_app": 34,
        "purchases_all": 65,
        "date": "2016-06-01"
      }
    ]};

    // create blank data table
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    // add columns: Type      Label
    data.addColumn('string', 'date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'website');
    data.addColumn('number', 'app');
    data.addColumn('number', 'all');

    // add each row from json
    dataJson.total_purchases.forEach(function (row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.date,
        row.purchases_website,
        row.purchases_app,
        row.purchases_all
      ]);
    });

    // sort data table
    data.sort([{column: 0}]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'chart '
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'week'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'counts',
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          max: 300,
          min: 0
        }
      },
      bars: 'vertical',
      width: 600,
      height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('the_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="the_chart"></div>
```

**notes:**

1. the above uses a discrete axis (first column is type: `'string'`)
   in order to use a continuous axis (type: `'datetime'`),
   you may want to change the format of the json `"date"` value,
   from --> `"2016-06-01"`
   to   --> `"06/01/2016"`
   when loaded in the data table,
   the current format will be offset by the timezone and could show an incorrect date,
   it may also cause the data points to not align correctly with gridlines

and if using type: `'datetime'`, first column will change to...

```
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'date');
```

and the add row statement would be...

```
  data.addRow([
    new Date(row.date),
    row.purchases_website,
    row.purchases_app,
    row.purchases_all
  ]);
```

2. recommend using *core* chart instead, there are several config options that don't work with *material* charts

[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*core* --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- using --> `packages: ['corechart']`

*material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- using --> `packages: ['bar']`

there is an option to get *core* chart close to look & feel of *material*

`theme: 'material'`

Comment: hope this helps -- i noticed the last object in your json had different properties from the rest, so i left it out --> `id` vs. `number` & `purchases` vs. `purchases_all`

Comment: Dude. WhiteHat. Your answers are getting super complete. +1. I don't know how you do it, but keep up the awesome.

Comment: @WhiteHat aaah thank you o_O. now its much easier to understand for me! I tried so hard so far, but thank you, thank you!

Comment: @WhiteHat but one more question :D. i dont know, how you have sorted it. you just write this:  data.sort([{column: 0}]);    by which value it is sorted? its sorted by date? but it isnt, even if i switched to 'daytime'

Comment: see reference for [`sort` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_sort) -- the above answer sorts the data table by the first column (but sorting strings is unreliable), sorting on the first and second would be --> `data.sort([{column: 0}, {column: 1}]);` -- you mention `'daytime'` -- the column type should be `'datetime'` or `'timeofday'` -- but loading `'timeofday'` is different than `'datetime'` -- see [working with `'timeofday'`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday)

Comment: aah I unterstand... and its only for date right? I could not do it with numbers? Like in the json, when the Number is in a string, like so :  `"puchases_all": "31"` ? Can I format it too? because String in a google Charts isnt working so good, right?

Comment: right -- for number, instead of `new Date(row.date)` above -- it would be something like `parseFloat(row.numberColumn)` or `parseInt(row.numberColumn)` -- depending on number type...